# Symfony3 Could not load type error during form generation

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to build a form in Symfony 3 and am stuck with some issue which I think should be trivial to solve, but I guess I'm not looking at the correct place.

I have 2 objects, Entity and Supplier. 1 entity does have 1 supplier associated to it. 1 supplier can have many entities related to it. (One to Many association).

I'm trying to build the form for the Entity class, with a drop down list providing the supplier it has to be associated with.

Here is the Entity form class:

```
<?php

namespace VP\SupplierBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use VP\SupplierBundle\Entity\Supplier;
use VP\SupplierBundle\Repository\SupplierRepository;

class EntityType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('name')
                ->add('supplier', Supplier::class, array(
                    'class' => 'VPSupplierBundle:Supplier',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'query_builder' => function (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->findAllByIsDeleted(0);
                    },
                    'choice_label' => 'name'
                ))
                ->add('submitnew', SubmitType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Add Entity',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
        )));
    }
```

Here is my SupplierRepository which is supposed to be called:

```
<?php

namespace VP\SupplierBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * SupplierRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class SupplierRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function findAllByIsDeleted($isDeleted) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
        $qb
                ->where('s.isDeleted = :isDeleted')
                ->setParameter('isDeleted', $isDeleted);
        return $qb;
    }

}
```

Still, I get the following error:

> Could not load type "VP\SupplierBundle\Entity\Supplier"

Any idea where it could come from? Tried to look at the [official symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) and some forum topics but no luck so far...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Working solution provided by @Jeet

```
//  
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType as DoctrineEntityType;
//

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('name')
                ->add('supplier', DoctrineEntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'VPSupplierBundle:Supplier',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->findAllByIsDeleted(0);
                    },
                    'choice_label' => 'name'
                ))
                ->add('submitnew', SubmitType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Add Entity',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
        )));
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have `__toString()` in your `Supplier` Class defined?

Comment: Just created it in the Supplier class, no change though: 
   `public function __toString() {
        return $this->getName();
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it here wrong :

```
->add('supplier', Supplier::class, array(
    'class' => 'VPSupplierBundle:Supplier',
    'property' => 'name',
    'query_builder' => function (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->findAllByIsDeleted(0);
    },
    'choice_label' => 'name'
))
```

You are loading a `Supplier::class` which unknown to Form Type. I guess you should instead load a `EntityType::class` form type.

Check here the [document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html). You want to show a choice Field with association to entity, hence you need to have `EntityType::class`. To recognize the Entity Type, you are already providing your Entity identity through `class` option. So it makes clear.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Jeet for your feedback. Not sure to understand why I should call EntityType class here since I'm trying to integrate a dropdown list of Suppliers here.

Comment: @Vincent you need to make a distinction between a form type and the entity. You would indeed need to define this field as an EntityType. Have a look at the default form types available in Symfony here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html

Comment: Thanks a lot both for your replies, it's indeed working and my understanding was completely wrong! I will document the solution in the initial topic.